# how to insert data into table based on dates and frequency in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm new to MS Access and my question has two parts, I'm working on Database to schedule jobs based on [StartDate], [EndDate] and [Frequency(Days)] of task, for example if the startdate is 01/01/2015 and the enddate is 31/12/2015 and Frequency is 30 days, then the query should add 12 dates like 31/01/2015, 01/03/2015, 31/03/2015....26/12/2015.

The second part of my question, if after two months I have changed the date like instead of 31/03/2015 the date has been changed manually to 05/04/2015 then the data should automatically changed from 05/04/2015 until 31/12/2015 without changing the completed dates from 01/01/2015 to 05/04/2015.

Comment: For the first part, look at DateAdd and a numbers table. Come back with some SQL / Code and where you are stuck.

Comment: hi Fionnuala, i have managed the first part through Append() Function, 
Dim dt As Date             'Loop controller
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset     'Table to append records to.
If DateDiff("m", Me.txtBegin, Me.txtEnd) > 1 Then
  dt = Me.txtBegin '+ Me.rank
  Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset("output reschedule query", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
  With rs
    Do While dt <= txtEnd
      .AddNew
        !Date = dt
        !Sno = Me.Text2
        .Update
      dt = DateAdd("d", Me.rank, dt)
     Loop
  End With
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "Generate"
  rs.Close
End If

Set rs = Nothing

End Function

Comment: but i dont know how to do the second part of this programing, what i want is to recalculating the dates if the Actual date is changed. the change should be done for the rest of not attended dates.